# Google Form: how to record the time taken to complete the whole form

Tags: google-forms

I'm running a survey and since there's a financial incentive to answer the form, I'd like to use the time taken to complete the form as one of the criteria of seriousness.

How can it be computed and then recorded in a row of the Google spreadsheet?